# Split screen in 2 divs and set second width with remaining space in css?

Tags: css, html, split, screen

I have 2 block-inline divs.

I don't wan't to specify the width of the first one but, I would like the second takes 100% of the remaining space. The container of the two divs take 100% of my screen.

It seems to be possible using jQuery to determine the width of the first div and to set the second value, but I would like to do it in pure css.

How can I do that ?

Comment: so the 1st div will have the width based on the content am i right??

Comment: Exactly. The left one is based on the content. The right one must have the remaining size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: You'll have to specify a width to one of the divs at a minimum using either percentages or pixels.

Comment: @Scott It is not possible to have to dynamics width ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
div.box {
  background: #EEE;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
}

div.div1 {
  background: #999;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

div.div2 {
  background: #666;
  height: 100%;
}

div.clear {
  clear: both;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0pt;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <div class="div1">1st</div>
   <div class="div2">2nd</div>
   <div class="clear">
</div>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: yes to obtain the width of the content and also the height in div2 to that it will not create a nextline or go down.

Comment: Can someone help me.. why is the class clear used in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jquery then this might worth doing

```
<div style="width:100%;"> 
        <div style="float:left; display:inline-block;" class="div1">left div</div> 
        <div style="float:right; display:inline-block;" class="div2">right div</div> 
    </div> ​
```

Comment: I specified I didn't want to use jQuery.

Comment: div will not take 100% of remaining space but will use content width.